# rbind values in plyr

Tags: r, plyr, rbind

I have a table with 2 columns and I'd like to combine values of the same factor level in one row, for example, I make a simplifed version here,

```
> df <- data.frame(x = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 2), y = 1:6)
x y
A 1
B 2
C 3
A 4
B 5
C 6
```

and I want it to be:

```
x  y
A  1, 4
B  2, 5
C  3, 6
```

so I tried `plyr`:

```
> library(plyr)
> d <- ddply(df, .(x), summarise, y = c(rbind(y)))
x y
A 1
A 4
B 2
B 5
C 3
C 6
```

What kind of mistake did I make and how can I get the format I want? I tested with `c(rbind(df$y))` before using `plyr` and the result seemed plausible while it didn't work out well. Thanks for any help!

**Update**
I also tried `d <- ddply(df, .(x), summarise, y = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(paste(y), split = ' '))))`, it returned the same result with no aggregation based on x.

Comment: Seems like you want `aggregate(y ~ x, df, list)` to keep the values as numeric.

Comment: Thanks to @RichardScriven , it's a simple and effective way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` the elements in 'y' together grouped by 'x'.  For this, we can use one of the group by methods.  Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'x', we `paste` the 'y' elements within that group.

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, list(y= toString(y)), by = x]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we use the same methodology.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    summarise(y= toString(y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! although the returned y is string, I need to `as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(y, split = ', ')))` so y is ready for future calculation.

Comment: I also updated my question, because I still don't understand why what I did couldn't group the data by x. Could you shed some light on it? Thanks!

Comment: @leoce The solutions in my post gives `y` as a `character` string.  If you wanted `y` to be `numeric`, you can place it in a `list` (as RichardScriven mentioned), i.e. `setDT(df)[, list(y=list(y)), by = x]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! data.table is also great for the further data working down this line.